# Is this possible using a rewrite rule, and if it is how?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have set up a php script to receive url data like this:

```
http://giffgaff.liamwli.co.uk/?name=liamwli
```

I want to make it so that I can go to

```
http://giffgaff.liamwli.co.uk/liamwli
```

And it would be re-written accordingly.

I have tried multiple online generators and none worked, so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that URL Rewrites are technically for URLs, not query parameters.

That said, there's a way to do this using RewriteCond to match on the QUERY_STRING:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/$              /%1          [L,R=302]
```

This should grab the value of name and populate it in the rewrite rule.

**EDIT** Oh crap I got your request backwards.  OK you actually want to do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+) /?name=%1 [L,R=302]
```

Also, this is more of a ServerFault question since it's not really programming related.

Comment: That doesn't work, I get a 404 error when putting /liamwli - why?